# How to make multiple lines become a single line in BigQuery?

Tags: replace, google-bigquery

I have a database that has a field containing cells with multiple lines like in the picture below

[image]

Instead of separated by an `'enter'/new line`, I'd like them to be combined as one line so that I can export them to CSV without any problem.

I've tried using `REPLACE(rejection_reason, '\n', '')` but it gives me the same output.
Is there any workaround on this?

Thank you

Comment: what data type of that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, `REPLACE(rejection_reason, '\n', '')` should work well. However, it might be related to Windows-like line separator - `\r\n`. I would suggest you to try:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(rejection_reason, '[\n\r]', '')
```